# How do programming languages/libraries communicate with hardware?

Tags: c#, c++, api, windows-phone-7, programming-languages

so I was looking into if there was any way to get around the XNA/Silverlight lockdown Microsoft has set up for the Windows Phone 7, as so maybe I could use SFML(.net binding) for application development and other libraries I've come to know.
*I found none.....*

Now all I'm wondering is why the windows phone and other similar devices don't allow some languages and unmanaged libraries such as OpenGL to be used, especially since I just found out about *platform invocation/ external linkage/ other bilingual techniques.*

To understand this I guess I need to undersand the relationship between a language and a machines hardware: **How does a c/c++ library like OpenGL communicate with the screen/graphics card ?**

*bonus question:* XNA doesn't use OpenGL/DirectX so is it an entirely independent graphics API?

Comment: XNA is a Managed Wrapper for DirectX!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX

Comment: Each video manufacturer (AMD/NVidia/Intel) providers *their own* OpenGL drivers and are coded to do the appropriate low-level bit twiddling for *their* hardware (this is why [most] drivers run as part of the Kernel). This layer can be wrapped a number of ways -- but this is the "core" of how it works.

Comment: @pst : So windows phones just don't have OpenGL supporting drivers? And what's the Kernel?

Comment: @Griffin Someone somewhere has coded the appropriate low-level driver for the hardware, whatever hardware may be. A [Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) can be *generally* thought of of bit of the operating system which concerns itself with bridging hardware access (e.g. "where drivers live").

Comment: @pst : by that do you mean that every new piece of hardware is required to have an OpenGL driver with it? Why can't a WP7 use OpenGL then?

Answer (score 3):

The Operation System encapsulate all the Hardware with the same API. In the OS internal, it used the hardware io address to control it.

And the OpenGL/DirectX/XNA encapsulate all the OS's system API with a simple, easy used interface to all the program upon it.

Just like below:

```
Hardware <- HAL <- DirectX / OpenGL <- XNA <- Your Program
```

Hope this helpful:)

Jason

Comment: thanks Jason, but what is HAL ? And does this mean an OS like Windows uses other venders hardware and their API's to communicate/control the hardware, but simply organizes all the commands together in a neat/easy to use way?

Comment: HAL is Hardware Abstraction Layer (wikipedia...) Operating system vendors create specific methods that each vendor needs to create.  When the OS calls the method, the vendor then has the hardware do whatever it is the method is for.

Comment: "HAL is Hardware Abstraction Layer"  right :)

Answer (score 3):

An extended pipeline would look like:

```
Hardware <- Vendor Drivers <- HAL (Operating System) <- OS Native Methods (DirectX/OpenGL) <- Managed Wrappers (XNA / .Net Frameworks / Java) <- Your Program
```

There are a few different reasons why vendors lock down devices.

1. Locked devices tend to have less technical issues, and Verizon etc don't want to fix Apple/Microsoft/Google/Motorola/Blackberry software issues.
2. Locked devices can be (not always) more secure because there is less chance for third parties to write bad drivers/software.
3. OpenGL initial/current design was/is not intented run on a mobile platforms.
4. Locked devices can create increased revenue by the OS Manufacturer as some require you to purchase development software and/or development licenses to write software.

I'm not especially excited about any of these, but they just come to mind.